ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets: The specified procedure could not be found
I've been using PyQT5 for ages. I'm very frustrated because out of NOWHERE I started getting this DLL error, and none of the solutions are working.
I've already tried:
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine-qt5
pip install PyQtWebEngine-qt5
pip install PyQtWebEngine

pip install --force-reinstall pyqt5

EVEN when I create a new conda environment I get the SAME error.
I'm on python 3.8
I've already tried:
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine-qt5
pip install PyQtWebEngine-qt5
pip install PyQtWebEngine

pip install --force-reinstall pyqt5.

I was expecting it to work as it worked for everyone else, but no matter what I try (the solutions are very limited from what I've seen) nothing has worked.

Such errors don't normally pop out randomly. Either you did something or your system (or some related program) did, even if it doesn't seem related and even if you didn't realize it. Also, forcing a reinstall doesn't imply that it's the same as uninstalling and installing again. Besides, without knowing more about your environment (including your OS version, for which you should also check about recent updates) we cannot really help you more.

I'm running on a windows 10 64 bit. my exact OS build is 19045.4291, and version is 22H2. im on python 3.8 and am using a conda environment. I currently don't have any updates required. The only thing I did differently was install GDAL (which I already had in the first place same version and everything)

what is the error message ?
